# @decorator get Class.__name__ of @staticmethod and @classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapt

A decorator `@wrapper` is using the `wrapt` library to access the wrapped function's class to get the class's name. Using it on `Animal.method()` and `foo()` works as expected.

**Problem:** However, the method `Animal.classy` decorated with `@classmethod` is giving `type` as its class name, and the method `Animal.static` decorated with `@staticmethod` is unable to retrieve its class.

Is it possible for `@wrapper` decorator function to obtain the class name `Animal` for `Animal.classy()` and `Animal.static()`?

**Expected Output**

```
foo
Animal.method
Animal.classy
Animal.static
```

**Obtained Output**

```
foo
Animal.method
type.classy
static
```

**Code to reproduce**

```
import wrapt
import time

@wrapt.decorator
def wrapper(wrapped, instance, args, kw):
    if instance is not None:
        print(f'\n{instance.__class__.__name__}.{wrapped.__name__}')
    else:
        print('\n' + wrapped.__name__)
    result = wrapped(*args, **kw)
    return result

@wrapper
def foo():
    time.sleep(0.1)

class Animal:
    @wrapper
    def method(self):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    @wrapper
    @classmethod
    def classy(cls):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    @wrapper
    @staticmethod
    def static():
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()                   # foo
    Animal().method()       # Animal.method
    Animal.classy()         # type.classy
    Animal.static()         # static
```

Comment: Why do you call classy and static on the class and not on the instance, as you do with method? Try doing `Animal().classy()` and `Animal().static()`

Comment: I'm not sure how you would detect the distinction you are looking for. `method` is getting an instance of `Animal` as an argument, but `classy` is just getting an instance of `type`. `static`, of course, isn't getting any argument. None of the three objects knows that they are used as class attributes of `Animal`, and so that information isn't available, in general, in the body of `wrapper`.

Comment: That is, `Animal.method` refers to a function object, but that function object doesn't know that it is referenced as an `Animal` class attribute. The same goes for the functions bound to `Animal.classy` and `Animal.static`.

Comment: @Pynchia Whether you use `Animal.classy()` or `Animal().classy()`, `classy` is still just getting a reference to `Animal` (an instance of `type`) as an argument.

Comment: @chepner I think `Animal.method` does know the class name. Since it knows the instance it belongs to, it can do `instance.__class__` to get the instance's class, and hence `instance.__class__.__name__` to get the class name. My example was able to show this.

Comment: You could add an explicit check to see if `instance.__class__` is `type` or not, but then you are assuming that you are only wrapping instance of classes whose metaclass is `type`. Maybe that's sufficient for your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having is that the arg `instance` is the value for the first parameter of any method. So for a regular method this will be it's `self` value and for a class method it'll be the `cls` value. For a static method you have no first/instance parameter so it behaves as if it were a function and `instance` is `None`.

So let's walk through your code. You call `foo`, your wrapper checks if `instance` is set, it is not since functions don't get an instance parameter, so it prints out the name of the function.

Next you call `method` on an instance of `Animal`. Your wrapper checks if `instance` is set, which it is since methods get an instance parameter, so it prints out the name of the class for `instance` and the name of the method.

Next you call `classy` on the class `Animal`. Your wrapper checks if `instance` is set, which it is since class methods get an instance parameter, so it prints out the name of the class for `instance` and the name of the class method. However in this case `instance` is the class that the method is defined on so when you do `instance.__class__` it retrieves the metaclass for your `Animal` class which is `type`. So what you actual want in this case is to add a check `if isinstance(instance, type)` and in that case you want to do `print(f"{instance.__name__}.{wrapped.__name__}")` since instance is your class in this case.

Finally you call the static method `static` on your class `Animal`. When you declare a method static it behaves as a normal function. So your wrapper checks if `instance` is set and finds that it is not, since functions don't get instance parameters, so moves on and just prints the name of the function. There's no standard way I know of to detect a static method.

So in summary to answer your exact questions. Is it possible to get the class name for `classy`? Yes. And is it possible to get the class name for `static`? Not that I'm aware of.

For further information on implementing a decorator that can be applied in different contexts, see:

- https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html#universal-decorators

In particular it provides the example:

```
import inspect

@wrapt.decorator
def universal(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    if instance is None:
        if inspect.isclass(wrapped):
            # Decorator was applied to a class.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Decorator was applied to a function or staticmethod.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        if inspect.isclass(instance):
            # Decorator was applied to a classmethod.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Decorator was applied to an instancemethod.
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
```

That may help in understanding what steps would need to be taken in each case to calculate the name.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing first post on Stackoverflow! Welcome!

Comment: Np, glad I could contribute. Been a long time lurker haha